# Roblox: SurfaceGUI does not have CanvasSize property

Tags: roblox

SurfaceGUI does not have CanvasSize property as can be seen in this image: https://postimg.cc/CZPgFX14

Searching for CanvasSize in the Explorer returns no results.

The CanvasSize property should be below the "AlwaysOnTop" property as seen in this image: https://images.contentstack.io/v3/assets/bltc2ad39afa86662c8/bltcdf38e0fefa655df/5c58c9f5194b42e50bc97905/forLoopBridge_setSurfaceGUISize.png?disposition=inline

I've tried to set the x,y values using a script with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Set "SizingMode" property to "FixedSize", Pixels per stud is a new feature